# TP-LINK TL823N Fail to Start in Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, drivers, kali-linux, realtek

I've a wifi card TL823N by TP-LINK which is based on Realtek rtl8192eu chipset. I've installed driver for that somehow but a new problem arises. The dmesg commands gives following output.

```
root@Chirag:~# dmesg
[ 1613.943294] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 1614.234650] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2357, idProduct=0109
[ 1614.234663] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1614.234668] usb 1-2: Product: 802.11n NIC 
[ 1614.234673] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Realtek 
[ 1614.234677] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00e04d044001
[ 1625.745018] 8192eu: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[ 1627.093158] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1627.093170] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 1627.093174] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth),     (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 1627.093183] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1627.093190] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1627.093195] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1627.093203] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1627.093210] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1627.093216] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1627.093221] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1627.093226] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
```

The result from 'uname -a' command

```
root@Chirag:~# uname -a
Linux Chirag 4.3.0-kali1-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-5kali4 (2016-01-13) i686 GNU/Linux
```

The device was unable to start.

This is link to driver files from the vendor http://www.tp-link.com/res/down/soft/TL-WN823N(EU)_V2_160315_Linux.zip

I make changes in Makefile at line 89 and from line 973 - 982

Please take a look here [Makefile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Aw7HDSIcUsMG9qWF9KUVJDLWc/view?usp=docslist_api)

Comment: The module seems to be compiled for another kernel version; however as you do not tell us in the question how you installed it, it is not entirely clear if this is the problem.

Comment: I installed this by making some changes in Makefile

Comment: You should really update your question directly with the makefile changes.  Links may, and often do, die.  Also, you're compiling a kernel module, it would be useful to provide `uname -a` and the version of `kernel-headers` package you're using.

Comment: I added direct from Google drive for that file

Answer (score -2):

Instala éste driver https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver, es más actualizado

(Install this driver; it's more recent.)

Comment: Please, use English here.

Comment: This might be a good answer. Can you expand it to explain how @Chirag should install it, please?